# Linux Mint and android x86 grub repair

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, android

I installed on my laptop an .iso of android. I have partitioned it the way that Linux Mint would stay on sda1 and Android on sda3, but now I don't see anymore the option to boot Linux Mint on the grub that android installed. What should I do to fix this ?

Thank you ! I think the grub menu is different from android-x86-4.4-RC2, Im afraid to do something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to a Linux Mint live media. Install Boot Repair and use it to install grub and reconfigure it in Linux Mint. It will probe for all installed OSes and add them to grub